# How to count a numeric variable then create a new ordinal count variable by unique identifier

Tags: r, time-series

I have weekly data that I am trying to summarize for all participants by their week in a study.

For example, `record_id` had a `rem_avg` on `w1`, a `rem_avg` on `w2`, etc.

My dataset is below. The variable `record_id` is a unique identifier, `week` is the numeric indicator of which week in the year the data comes from, `rem_avg` is the mean sleep value. I also have a `timestamp` variable not shown that I used `lubridate::week()` on to get the `week` variable.

```
head(awake_sensor, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   record_id [4]
   record_id  week rem_avg 
   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>     
 1 10            2   0.267   
 2 10            3   0.352   
 3 10            4   0.256   
 8 11            9   0.162   
 9 11           10   0.168   
10 11           11   0.169   
11 11           12   0.262   
12 11           13   0.333   
13 11           14   0.18   
14 12            3   0.207   
15 12            4   0.24   
19 13            9   0.369  
20 13           10   0.464
```

Ideally it would look something like this when I'm done, with the `week_indicator` representing which week the data came from:

```
   record_id  week rem_avg   week_indicator
   <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <chr>  
 1 10            2   0.267     1
 2 10            3   0.352     2
 3 10            4   0.256     3
 8 11            9   0.162     1
 9 11           10   0.168     2
10 11           11   0.169     3
11 11           12   0.262     4
12 11           13   0.333     5
13 11           14   0.18      6
14 12            3   0.207     1
15 12            4   0.24      2
19 13            9   0.369     1
20 13           10   0.464     2
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution was much more simple than what I had been trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to group by 'record_identifier' and create the 'week_indicator' as the `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(record_identifier) %>%
   mutate(week_indicator = row_number())
```

---

Or using `rowid` from `data.table`, can skip the `group_by` and directly create the column

```
library(data.table)
df %>%
   mutate(week_indicator = rowid(record_identifier))
```